# How to filter date range from "date" - 2 weeks and "date" + 2 weeks

Tags: sql, date-range, days, exasolution

I have a table t like:

```
VALID_FROM | VALID_TO   | stock
2020-10-01 | 2020-10-02 | 10
2020-10-02 | 2020-10-04 | 9
2020-10-04 | 2020-10-08 | 5
...        | ...        |
2020-12-15 | 2020-12-16 | 0
```

I need to set a date range for a specific date from:

'2020-11-26' - 2 weeks / 14 days
'2020-11-26' + 2 weeks / 14 days

I could just use fixed dates, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.VALID_FROM >= '2020-11-12'
AND t.VALID_TO <= '2020-12-10'
```

But the date range may change and I would like to just add days or weeks without having to use a calendar every time.

So something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.VALID_FROM >= '2020-11-26' - INTERVAL '14' DAY
AND t.VALID_TO <= '2020-11-26' + INTERVAL '14' DAY
```

But that gives me the error message:

> Feature not supported: Cannot cast from INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(3) to DOUBLE

Comment: You can try the DATEADD(d, -14, '2020-11-26')  and DATEADD(d, 14, '2020-11-26') with a BETWEEN clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`add_days()`](https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/add_days.htm) function:

```
WHERE t.VALID_FROM >= add_days('2020-11-26', -14) AND
      t.VALID_TO <= add_days('2020-11-26', -14)
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt' know about add_days() till now.